# adding or recognizing multiple textboxes or something like that in php dynamically

Tags: php, mysqli, textbox, web, data-retrieval

hi
i am amateur in php and making a website in which i am uploading an image,storing it in database(with an autoincrement variable) and displaying it on page in descending order so it may seem as latest at top and latter below it,,i need to add a textbox for comment and username(cuz i haven't made login page as m not gonna host it somewhere)
i knwo how to add it for upload image's section as only 1 image is gonna get uploaded 
problem is how to display it, i have used

```
while ($image = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
echo image code....
}
```

Now i in the div to display image i'll incorporate 2 textboxes and evertime after while loop ill display values from dB accordingly but when i want to edit the textbox after uploading more than 1 image,how to know which textbox is being edited as every textbox would have same textbox name
should i compare the image contents ?as the image iteself is stored in binary format?
 but that wud be a slow process i guess
plz suggest som idea or method to do so
 basically its like instagram(but very basic)....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create images table:

---

**images** table

image_id   |  url

---

Then creare seperate table for images comments:

---

**images_comments** table

comment_id   |    image_id    |    user    |    text   |   date

---

Where:

> **comment_id:** integer , Auto Increment
>   **image_id:** integer referring to id in images table 
>   **user:** should be user id referring to separate users table, but because you do not have login system you can store user name here as varchar. 
>   **text:** varchar 
>   **date:** datetime

**To show images + comments:**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM images";

while ($image = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
   $imageUrl = $image["url"];
   $imageID = $image["image_id"];

   //Show image:
   echo "<img src='$imageUrl ' />";

   //Get comments:
   $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM images_comments WHERE image_id=$imageID";
   while ($comment = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql2))
   {
      $text = $comment["text"];
      $userName = $comment["user"];
      $date = $comment["date"];       
      //show username and comment date
      echo $userName . " " .$date . "<br>";
      //Show comment text:
      echo $text; 
   }
}
```

**To add a comment to images** 
if you want a comment form under each image then in the While loop we used before add the following code:

```
while ($image = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
    .......... previous code goes here .........

    //in the form we store imageID in hidden input field
    //so that we can know to which image the form belongs
    echo "<form method='post' action='page.php'>
             <input type='text' name='username'/>
             <textarea name='commentText'></textarea>
             <input type='hidden' name='imageID' value='$imageID'/>
             <input type='submit' name='submitComment' value='Submit'>
          </form>";

}
```

**then in page.php**

```
if(isset($_POST["submitComment"]))
{
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $text = $_POST["commentText"];
    $imageID = $_POST["imageID"];
    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    $sql = "INSERT INTO images_comments (image_id,user,text,date) VALUES
            ($imageID,$username,$text,$date)";
    mysqli_query($con,$sql);
}
```

Comment: big thanx deepblue,havent implemented but urely will giv a feedback when i'll try but i have a doubt that why should i echo the form in while loop?cannot i just put it in index.php without the while loop?this is silly question but please explain ...

Comment: ok i got the reason...But in the second code u said "if you want a comment form under each image then in the While loop we used before add the following code" but i need to add the comment section at the time of uploading the image so wud this code work:
             <input type='text' name='username'/>
             <textarea name='commentText'></textarea>

???

Comment: thanx mahn,,that helped!!
Now i want to know how to add 'add comment' section,,like dynamically adding textbox,,does onclick event on 'add comment' which again shows form similar to abov will work??
Also i want to know how to add a like button or something like dat...

Thanx again for the help.......

Comment: You are welcome, if you want to enable comment only on upload then dont put the form in the while loop under each image. Show it once in upload page, and you process the code I used in page.php example inside your (upload.php) file

Comment: Now if you want to add comment button under each image then simply put the comment form back in the while loop (exactly as in my example).. Then put the form inside hidden div <div id="comment-box"><form>....</form></div> which you hide in css (display:none).

Comment: Then add comment button like <a class="comment">comment</a>.. then show comment-box using Jquery example: $(".comment").click(function(){  $(this).closest("#comment-box").show();});

Comment: thanx i'll try that ,also tel me howto add or upvote or a like button ? :P :P